# Get Element Value according to another element in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to retrieve the Code of supplier according to the price retrieved previously

the price was retrieved like so

```
<xsl:template match="Price">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/Price">
    <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

is there anything i can do to get the supplier code for that price

```
<xsl:variable name="SupplierCode" select="current-group()/SupplierCode"/>
```

XML Sample

```
<Search-Request search-term="1 tb">
    <Items>
        <Item href="SEA1TBST31000524AS.jpg" model="ST31000524AS">
            <Name>Seagate Hard disk 1TB ST31000524AS 3.5"</Name>
            <Price>60.50</Price>
            <SupplierCode>TECSEA1TB</SupplierCode>
            <Supplier>TEC001</Supplier>
            <Manufacturer>Seagate</Manufacturer>
        </Item>
        <Item href="" model="ST31000524AS">
            <Name>Seagate Hard disk 1TB ST31000524AS 3.5 inch</Name>
            <Price>55.50</Price>
            <SupplierCode>SCASEA1TB</SupplierCode>
            <Supplier>SCA001</Supplier>
            <Manufacturer>Seagate</Manufacturer>
        </Item>
     </Items>
 </Search-Request>
```

also I am grouping in the following manner.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Items/Item" group-by="@model">
```

Comment: Can we see the source XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like for each "model", you are trying to find the cheapest Item for that model.

To get the **SupplierCode** for the current **Price** element you are on, you could just do this...

```
<xsl:template match="Price">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="../SupplierCode" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Where `..` is used to get the parent of the current node.

Alternatively, what you could do is instead of selecting the **Price** elements with you template, select the **Item** element, ordered by **Price**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
    <xsl:sort select="Price" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Then, you can have a template matching the **Item** element, and in this you be easily able to access the **Price** and **Code**

```
<xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="Price" />
        <xsl:value-of select="Code" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT: In answer to your comment, if you only wanted the SupplierCode for the Item with the lowest price, you would change the template matching the **Item** element to output just the supplier code, and then wrap the **xsl:apply-templates** in a variable.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:for-each-group select="Items/Item" group-by="@model">
      <xsl:variable name="SupplierCode">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
            <xsl:sort select="Price" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="$SupplierCode" />
   </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="SupplierCode"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actually, there is another way of doing this. You could make use of the **min** operator in XSLT 2.0

```
   <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[number(Price)=min(current-group()/Price)]/SupplierCode" />
```

This wouldn't necessarily be as efficient as the previous method though because you are effectively checking the "current-group()" twice. First to get the minimum value, and then again to find the Item in the current-group with the lowest price.

Comment: I'm sorry I may be asking something stupid but how would I retrieve the Supplier Code by itself then?

Comment: I've expanded my answer to hopefully make it clearer.